# Rails - Is there a way to update a single attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller, models

I was just wondering, I have a model that, besides the id's from other models (FK), it has a single attribute `boolean`. I want to know how can I create a button that changes this `boolean` and just that

My model in question is this one:

```
class Squad
 belongs_to :player
 belongs_to :team
end
```

I want to create a button on the `team#show` page so the `player` that owns this `team` can change the `boolean` of `squad`. How can I do this and how would look like my controllers?

Thanks :)!

**-Edit-**

I'm using a link like this:

```
<%=link_to("Change status", squad_path(sqd, :status => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?")%>
```

Where `sqd` is part of my query. Is this link wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<%= link_to("Change status", squad_path(sqd, "squad[status]" => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?") %>
```

in your controller (it is pretty common)

```
def update
  @squad = Squad.find params[:id]
  if @squad.update_attributes params[:squad]
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the missing part :)

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi, yes, it is just a mistype of course and it is not the point of the answer

Comment: I thought the point of the question was how to update a single attribute on a model not multiple. Regardless glad that the poster got the solution. :) cheers

Comment: @fl00r's answer helped me figure out my error. I did it without the method in the controller though.
`<% boolval_state = modelname.boolval ? "Y" : "N"; boolval_flip = modelname.boolval ? false : true; %>`
`<%= link_to  boolval_state, modelname_path(modelname, "modelname[boolval]" => boolval_flip), method: :put %>`

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. The method is called "update_attribute". It takes two arguments, the name of the field and the value.

```
  squad.update_attribute(:boolean_field,true) # or false
```

Based on updated question

```
def update
  @squad = Squad.find(params[:id])
  if @squad.update_attribute(:status,params[:status])
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I'm trying to create a link to it but isn't working, its updating all the models in the page :/
I have a query to find the squads in question, do you think this is the best way or there is other possible thing I could do?

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of your attributes ?

Since it belongs to `player`, you can access it with `player.squad.name_of_your_attributes = new_value`. Don't forget to `save` your object if you want the changes to be saved in your DB.

Also, you could read [that](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

EDIT: fl00r answered your edited question, no need that i repeat what he wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question. Could you change the link my link into the one you proposed? :)